# Converting dictionaries to list sorted by values, with multiple values per item

Tags: python, dictionary

In Python, I have a simple problem of converting lists and dictionaries that I have solved using explicit type check to tell the difference between integers and list of integers. I'm somewhat new to python, and I'd curious if there is a more 'pythonic' way to solve the problem,i.e. that avoids an explicit type check.

In short: Trying to sort a dictionary's keys using the values, but where each key can have multiple values, and the key needs to appear multiple times in the list. Data comes in the form `{'a':1, 'b':[0,2],...}`. Everything I have come up (using sorted( , key = ) ) with is tripped up by the fact the values that occur once can be specified not as an integer instead of a length of list 1.

I'd like to convert between dictionaries of the form `{'a':3, 'b':0, 'c':[2,4], 'd':[1,5]}` and lists `['b', 'd', 'c', 'a', 'c', 'd']` (the positions of the items in list being specified by the values in the dictionary).

The function `list_to_dictionary` should have a key for each item appearing in the list with the value giving the location in the list. In case an item appears more than once, the value should be a list storing all of those locations.

The function `dictionary_to_list` should create a list consisting of the keys of the dictionary, sorted by value. In case the value is not a single integer but instead a list of integers, that key should appear in the list multiple times at the corresponding sorted locations.

My solution was as follows:

```
def dictionary_to_list(d):
"""inputs a dictionary a:i or a:[i,j], outputs a list of a sorted by i"""    
    #Converts i to [i] as value of dictionary
    for a in d:
        if type(d[a])!=type([0,1]):
            d[a] = [d[a]]

    #Reverses the dictionary from {a:[i,j]...} to {i:a, j:a,...}
    reversed_d ={i:a for a in d for i in d[a]}

    return  [x[1] for x in sorted(reversed_d.items(), key=lambda x:x[0])]

def list_to_dictionary(x):
    d = {}        
    for i in range(len(x)):
        a = x[i]            
        if a in d:
            d[a].append(i)
        else:
            d[a]=[i]
    #Creates {a:[i], b:[j,k],...}

    for a in d:
        if len(d[a])==1:
            d[a] = d[a][0]
    #Converts to {a:i, b:[j,k],...}

    return d
```

I can't change the problem to have lists of length 1 in place of the single integers as the values of the dictionaries due to the interaction with the rest of my code. It seems like there should be a simple way to handle this but I can't figure it out. A better solution here would have several applications for my python scripts.

Thanks

Comment: You could try to unify your representation of the values in the dict to always be lists. That way you do not need to disambiguate them to int or list. Your example would become: `{'a':[3], 'b':[0], 'c':[2,4], 'd':[1,5]}`

Comment: I think it would be difficult to do this without checking the type.

Comment: That is certainly the first idea I came up with. However this code is part of a larger program where it makes sense to have only 1 item per key - the cases where I have two items per key are just intermediate steps. I constantly use the values of this dictionary in my programs, and it seems kind of hackish to always put an extra [0] everywhere I need that value. However, the other operations I need to do on these dictionaries are easy to do in the list format: for example concatenating the list, or deleting both instances of 'c' from the list, where the indices shift appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def dictionary_to_list(data):
    result = {}
    for key, value in data.items():
        if isinstance(value, list):
            for index in value:
                result[index] = key
        else:
            result[value] = key
    return [result[key] for key in sorted(result)]

def list_to_dictionary(data):
    result = {}
    for index, char in enumerate(data):
        result.setdefault(char, [])
        result[char].append(index)
    return dict((key, value[0]) if len(value) == 1 else (key, value) for key, value in result.items())

dictData = {'a':3, 'b':0, 'c':[2,4], 'd':[1,5]}
listData = ['b', 'd', 'c', 'a', 'c', 'd']

print dictionary_to_list(dictData)
print list_to_dictionary(listData)
```

**Output**

```
['b', 'd', 'c', 'a', 'c', 'd']
{'a': 3, 'c': [2, 4], 'b': 0, 'd': [1, 5]}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In [17]: d = {'a':3, 'b':0, 'c':[2,4], 'd':[1,5]}

In [18]: sorted(list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([[k]*(1 if isinstance(d[k], int) else len(d[k])) for k in d])), key=lambda i:d[i] if isinstance(d[i], int) else d[i].pop(0))
Out[18]: ['b', 'd', 'c', 'a', 'c', 'd']
```

The call is to:

```
sorted(
  list(
    itertools.chain.from_iterable(
      [[k]*(1 if isinstance(d[k], int) else len(d[k])) 
        for k in d
      ]
    )
  ), 
  key=lambda i:d[i] if isinstance(d[i], int) else d[i].pop(0)
)
```

The idea is that the first part (i.e. `list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([[k]*(1 if isinstance(d[k], int) else len(d[k])) for k in d]))` creates a list of the keys in `d`, repeating by the number of values associated with it. So if a key has as single `int` (or a list containing only one `int`) as its value, it appears once in this list; else, it appears as many times as there are items in the list.

Next, we assume that the values are sorted (trivial to do as a pre-processing step, otherwise). So now, what we do is to sort the keys by their first value. If they have only a single int as their value, it is considered; else, the first element in the list containing all its values. This first element is also removed from the list (by the call to pop) so that subsequent occurrences of the same key won't reuse the same value

If you'd like to do this without the explicit typecheck, then you could listify all values as a preprocessing step:

```
In [22]: d = {'a':3, 'b':0, 'c':[2,4], 'd':[1,5]}

In [23]: d = {k:v if isinstance(v, list) else [v] for k,v in d.iteritems()}

In [24]: d
Out[24]: {'a': [3], 'b': [0], 'c': [2, 4], 'd': [1, 5]}

In [25]: sorted(list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([[k]*len(d[k]) for k in d])), key=lambda i:d[i].pop(0))
Out[25]: ['b', 'd', 'c', 'a', 'c', 'd']
```

Comment: still have to check the type of `v`. Do you think it's impossible to do this without any check? I do.

Comment: Either check at creation-time or do a preprocessing step. In either case, it needs to be checked. If you feel better about it, farm it to a function

Answer (score 0):

```
def dictionary_to_list(d):
    return [k[0] for k in sorted(list(((key,n) for key, value in d.items() if isinstance(value, list) for n in value))+\
    [(key, value) for key, value in d.items() if not isinstance(value, list)], key=lambda k:k[1])]

def list_to_dictionary(l):
    d = {}
    for i, c in enumerate(l):
        if c in d:
            if isinstance(d[c], list):
                d[c].append(i)
            else:
                d[c] = [d[c], i]
        else:
            d[c] = i
    return d
l = dictionary_to_list({'a':3, 'b':0, 'c':[2,4], 'd':[1,5]})
print(l)
print(list_to_dictionary(l))
```